# Glide exception when getting image from Firebase

Tags: android, imageview, firebase-storage, android-glide, firebaseui

I am trying to load an image from Firebase storage using glide:

```
StorageReference storageReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
StorageReference fileRef = storageReference.child("ProfileIcons/0.png");

Glide.with(getContext()).load(fileRef).into(img_profile_icon);
```

The reference is ok, the image exists but it gives me this error and the photo is not loaded:

```
E/GlideExecutor: Request threw uncaught throwable
    com.bumptech.glide.Registry$NoModelLoaderAvailableException: Failed to find any ModelLoaders for model: gs://firestoretest-13873.appspot.com/ProfileIcons/0.png
        at com.bumptech.glide.Registry.getModelLoaders(Registry.java:587)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeHelper.getLoadData(DecodeHelper.java:207)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeHelper.getCacheKeys(DecodeHelper.java:224)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.ResourceCacheGenerator.startNext(ResourceCacheGenerator.java:44)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:310)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:276)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:431)
W/Glide: Load failed for gs://firestoretest-13873.appspot.com/ProfileIcons/0.png with size [300x300]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
    There was 1 cause:
    com.bumptech.glide.Registry$NoModelLoaderAvailableException(Failed to find any ModelLoaders for model: gs://firestoretest-13873.appspot.com/ProfileIcons/0.png)
     call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
      Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.Registry$NoModelLoaderAvailableException: Failed to find any ModelLoaders for model: gs://firestoretest-13873.appspot.com/ProfileIcons/0.png
I/Glide: Root cause (1 of 1)
    com.bumptech.glide.Registry$NoModelLoaderAvailableException: Failed to find any ModelLoaders for model: gs://firestoretest-13873.appspot.com/ProfileIcons/0.png
        at com.bumptech.glide.Registry.getModelLoaders(Registry.java:587)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeHelper.getLoadData(DecodeHelper.java:207)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeHelper.getCacheKeys(DecodeHelper.java:224)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.ResourceCacheGenerator.startNext(ResourceCacheGenerator.java:44)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runGenerators(DecodeJob.java:310)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.runWrapped(DecodeJob.java:276)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DecodeJob.run(DecodeJob.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
        at com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.executor.GlideExecutor$DefaultThreadFactory$1.run(GlideExecutor.java:431)
```

I checked some solution and tried to add this into my class but still doesnt work:

```
@GlideModule
public static class MyAppGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {

    @Override
    public void registerComponents(Context context, Glide glide, Registry registry) {
        // Register FirebaseImageLoader to handle StorageReference
        registry.append(StorageReference.class, InputStream.class,
                new FirebaseImageLoader.Factory());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to follow all of the steps listed in the [documentation](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support).  You could be missing the step where you add an annotation processor dependency:

```
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.x'
```

Comment: I added it and I get the same error. Glide is working if i try to get dată from normal links, it only doesnt work with firebase